# Python 3.x - How to return a value from a function requiring arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return, global

I will preface by saying I'm not a programmer and this is the first forum post I'm making to StackOverflow. I am trying to find a way to return a value from a function so that I can use it in a separate .py file. I have tried making the variable global and returning a value. The problem is that this function is being called from a library belonging to watchdog.

```
    def on_created(event):
        import Check_Resume
        srcpth = event.src_path
        head, path, tail = srcpth.partition('\\uploads\\')
        return tail
    my_event_handler.on_created = on_created
    ResumeTitle = on_created()
    print(ResumeTitle)
```

The issue here is that there is an argument that is expected for the on_created() function which makes sense. I will see the error below:

> missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

This argument is already supplied by the watchdog library. I believe it's calling the function I have defined here. For this reason, I don't know what argument to pass. What I would like is to be able to assign the returned value from the function to a variable that can be used in a separate .py file. For simplicity sake, I would like just to print out the result.

Comment: From the little information that you posted, I can only _guess_ that the function shall not be called explicitly: `ResumeTitle = on_created` (no parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

if the `event` argument is given by a value from the `watchdog` library, why not just save it into a variable and use that?

```
argument_from_watchdog = function_from_watchdog(*args, **kwargs)
```

then use that on your function `on_created(argument_from_watchdog)`